# Targeting Angular object with jqlite

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a custom directive that contains a DOM element with an angular object and I would like to know how could I target the value of that object.
Here goes the example:

```
app.directive('x', function() {
return {
  scope: {},
  restrict: 'E',
  template: '<span class="oinky">{{box.size}}</span>',
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

    if({{box.size}}>50 && {{box.size}}<=65) {

    element.css("background", "rgba(255, 216, 61, 0.7)");

  }else if({{box.size}}>65 && {{box.size}}<80){

    element.css("background", "rgba(235, 149, 51, 0.7)");

  }else if({{box.size}}>=80){

    element.css("background", "rgba(189, 45, 40, 0.7)");

  }else{

    element.css("background", "rgba(185, 211, 50, 0.7)");

  }

  }    
};

});
```

Something like this. Sorry if I seem raw in my knowledge of the framework, but I am not being able to find any good answer on google or StackOverflow.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why are you using `{{box.size}}` in JavaScript code? `element.css()` ids perfectly fine.

Comment: The {{box.size}} is there as a placeholder, as I don't know how to target the specific value it represents. @Satpal

Comment: You are using isolate scope since using `scope: {},` and You must define `scope.box` like `scope.box = { size :10 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bit you're missing is how the user of this directive would be able to set the value of `box.size`. You've created an isolated scope with the declaration of `scope:{}`, so currently there is no way `box.size` could be set to anything.

Assuming you want this as an isolated component (i.e. not reading from the parent scope), you could set `boxsize` on the directive scope and have it set by the user when using the directive:

```
app.directive('x', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        boxSize:"=size"
      },
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<span class="oinky">{{boxSize}}</span>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if(scope.boxSize>50 && scope.boxSize<=65) {
            element.css("background", "rgba(255, 216, 61, 0.7)");
        } else if(scope.boxSize>65 && scope.boxSize<80){
            element.css("background", "rgba(235, 149, 51, 0.7)");
        } else if(scope.boxSize>=80){
            element.css("background", "rgba(189, 45, 40, 0.7)");
        } else{
            element.css("background", "rgba(185, 211, 50, 0.7)");
        }
      }    
    };
});
```

That could then be used:

```
<x size="55"/>
```

For more info on scopes with directives, look at the docs for `$compile` which is strangely the best place for directive information:  (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

**Update: Using parent scope**
To use the parent scope, simply remove the `scope: {}` part. It will then mean that the `scope` parameter to the `link` function will be that of the parent.

Something like:

```
 app.directive('x', function() {
        return {          
          restrict: 'E',
          template: '<span class="oinky">{{box.size}}</span>',
          link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            if(scope.box.size>50 && scope.box.size<=65) {
                element.css("background", "rgba(255, 216, 61, 0.7)");
            } else if(scope.box.size>65 && scope.box.size<80){
                element.css("background", "rgba(235, 149, 51, 0.7)");
            } else if(scope.box.size>=80){
                element.css("background", "rgba(189, 45, 40, 0.7)");
            } else{
                element.css("background", "rgba(185, 211, 50, 0.7)");
            }
          }    
        };
    });
```

Which assumes the the parent scope has a `box` object with a `size` property.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, but I would like to bring in the parent scope, so I can target it.

Comment: Updated answer. Just be aware of the trade-offs with which scope you use. For reusable components, isolated scope is more maintainable.

Comment: Yap, it worked. Thanks for troubleshooting, you helped me a lot and finally I situated the scope concept on my head.